# Word for what a piece of art is commenting on being reflected in the reaction to that art

Tags: single-word-requests

One of the messages behind *The Hunger Games* is that the people in The Capitol focus on the love triangle between Katniss, Gale, and Peeta, and don't realize how barbaric the games are. It's a chilling commentary on the blindness of people in the manipulation of media. However, what people talk quite a lot about when discussing Hunger Games *the book*, is whether or not Katniss should get with Gale vs. Peeta. People have missed the commentary, and replicated what Suzanne Collins is mocking.

Marina and The Diamonds released an album called, "Electra Heart," which was a concept album about how society views women. There's songs dedicated to each 'archetype,' of girl, songs discussing how women are glossed over and judged singularly on their beauty instead of talent, and songs where Marina sings about how women are pitted against each other in a way that men aren't. When people reacted to the album, they mocked how Marina was dressed in the music videos, how she sounded like Lana Del Rey, dissed her for not being a "real singer," and dismissed her as a silly girl. It was hilarious, and unfortunate.

I've been looking for a word to describe this situation, and the closest I've got is, "Irony."

> A state of affairs or an event that seems deliberately contrary to what one expects and is often amusing as a result.

While this is very descriptive of the situation for the rest of us who are in on the joke, I'm looking for a word that summarizes the situation **as it applies to the person making the mistake**, as in

> Janie read *The Hunger Games* and agonized about if Katniss would be happier with Gale, or with Peeta. Margret also read *The Hunger Games*, and told Janie she was being absolutely __

Comment: Hmm, no idea. I'd call these people "sheeple"... perhaps "sheeplism"? :)

Comment: @pookie ha! I've been going with 'morons,' but i was hoping for something more technical :p

Comment: Stick with morons; it's probably more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably call these people [**oblivious**](http://thefreedictionary.com/oblivious), as they are completely unaware of the deeper meaning behind the media they are consuming. You could also call them [**incognizant**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incognizant), another word to mean unaware.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because of incognizant, which hadn't even OCCURRED to me, but I find hilarious

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single word, but a common term when people don't get the point of something is **it goes over their head**.

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+over+head)

> 2. if a piece of information goes over someone's head, they do not understand it
>     *The bit about tax went straight over my head - was it important?*

On Internet message boards, this is often abbreviated as [*whoosh!*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Woosh), to express the sound the ideas make when they fly over the person's head.